A text message fails to appear in a shiny app
I am writing an app that fits a zero curve to observed bond prices. The shiny GUI is specified as follows:
  ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Curve fit"),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
      fluidRow(
        box(title="Messages",textOutput("Messages")),
        box(title = "...",
          selectInput("curveType", 
          label = "CurveType", 
          choices = c("NSS","Cubic Spline")
        )
      )),
      fluidRow(
        box(title="...",
          plotOutput("curvePlot",width = "100%", height = "400px")
        ),
        box(title="...",tableOutput("spreadTable"))
      )
    )
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    curveType <- reactive(input$curveType)
    refDate <- as.Date('2024-03-12')
    
    output$Messages <- renderText({"Fitting curve..."})
    # curve fit
    verboseLevel <- 1
    curveFit <- reactive(CurveFitting::fitCurve(
      curveType(),bondBaseData_df,refDate,verboseLevel
    ))
    
    output$Messages <- renderText({"Finished."})
    output$spreadTable <- renderTable({curveFit()$.spreadDF})
    output$curvePlot <- renderPlot({curvePlot(curveFit()$.zeroCurve)})
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)

The first message "Fitting curve" never appears but the second message "Finished" does.
What could be the reason and is there something wrong with the code above?

You overwrite the first definition of output$Messages with the second before the app is even displayed.  Shiny is reactive: the code within your server function does not execute sequentially.  To do what you want, you need a single definition of output$Messages that monitors (another) reactive value that indicates the status of the curve fitting.

Actually, that's wrong.  In simple cases, the log computation will block the UI updates.  Here's how to do it.

@Limey Thanks. If you post it as an official answer I will accept it.
